# git run installation fails

Tags: git, macos, npm

My computer is a Mac High Sierra 10.13.4.
I try to install git run from npm but it fails.
I run the install command without sudo. It fails and asks to run it as administrator.
But even as administrator it fails.

When I have a look at the folder

```
/Users/myuser/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-aaff9974
```

I see that it has 777. This is because I previously chmodded it with

```
chmod -R 777/Users/myuser/.npm/_cacache/tmp
```

However, the error I can see complains about permission for that folder.
This is the output of the 2 install command I run:

```
npm install -g git-run
npm ERR! path ../lib/node_modules/git-run/bin/gr
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink 
'../lib/node_modules/git-run/bin/gr' -> '/usr/local/bin/gr'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink 
'../lib/node_modules/git-run/bin/gr' -> '/usr/local/bin/gr'
npm ERR!   cause: 
npm ERR!    { Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink 
'../lib/node_modules/git-run/bin/gr' -> '/usr/local/bin/gr'
npm ERR!      errno: -13,
npm ERR!      code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!      syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!      path: '../lib/node_modules/git-run/bin/gr',
npm ERR!      dest: '/usr/local/bin/gr' },
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink 
\'../lib/node_modules/git-run/bin/gr\' -> \'/usr/local/bin/gr\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!   path: '../lib/node_modules/git-run/bin/gr',
npm ERR!   dest: '/usr/local/bin/gr' }
npm ERR! 
npm  ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/myuser/.npm/_logs/2018-05-11T07_44_18_858Z-debug.log
```

---

```
sudo npm install -g git-run
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! Command failed: /usr/bin/git clone -q 
https://github.com/mixu/node-tabtab.git 
/Users/myuser/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-aaff9974
npm ERR! /Users/myuser/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-aaff9974/.git: Permission denied
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/myuser/.npm/_logs/2018-05-11T07_44_32_203Z-debug.log
```

Comment: please show the output when you do it with `sudo`

Comment: I did it. It is almost at the end after the text "npm  ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator."

Comment: `rm -rf /Users/myuser/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-aaff9974/`, and rerun with sudo.

Comment: I tried it. But still no luck. Exactly the same error.

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions